# Infinitely long loaf of Bread

Tags: logical-deduction, lateral-thinking, story, open-ended

> You are visiting your old friend Mike at Infinitely's Baking Shop. Just
>   as you arrived, he was taking out a fresh, infinitely long loaf of
>   bread. Both of its ends extend infinitely long in a straight line. The smell of the breads displayed on the infinitely long shelves feels so good.
>
> But you know that Jesse, your roommate, only eats the crusts of the
>   bread (the ends of the bread). If you ask for the freshly baked bread,
>   you'll grab it by its center, and since it's infinite in both
>   directions, no finite speeds can bring you to either of its ends, and you
>   know you can't travel faster than light anyway.
>
> If you grab one of the loaves of bread from the display, you can grab it by one of
>   its ends and thus cut a single crust piece, but Jesse needs two, or
>   he'll stay hungry.
>
> You might consider buying two loaves of bread from the display to solve this dilemma, but
>   you can afford only one loaf and can't obtain more money for today by
>   any means. Nor can you obtain more loaves by any other means. Mike is also not very
>   giving, to just give you a loaf without receiving the money equaling
>   its total cost.
>
> [image]
>
> After standing there shortly, you came up with an idea. At the end of
>   the day, you walked out with two crusts in one hand, and the rest of
>   the infinitely long bread in your infinitely long bag carried in your
>   other hand. How did you manage to do it?

The picture represents a rough estimate of how a loaf of bread would look like if it was finite in length. (Mike only sells infinite breads)

The intended solution, in my opinion, is quite nice. I'm not sure if there are any other tricky means to solve the problem, but go for it.

---

**Edit:** The accepted answer, in my opinion, is simpler and better than the intended solution, and it can lead to a "problem" regarding infinities.

*Intended solution* hint:

> The "problem" could be represented as a disagreement between yourself and Mike, which can take place some moments after Mike already agreed to your proposal.

Added the "open-ended" tag because it is unknown how many ways the infinities of the loaves can be interpreted.

Comment: Why does Jesse have to be so picky?

Comment: How do you fit an infinitely long piece of bread in a bag? :P

Comment: @BeastlyGerbil It's an infinitely long bag, as it says in the story.

Comment: Is Jesse picky about his 'crust slices' having to be sliced exactly with a plan perpendicular to the loafs axis?

Comment: Also how has Mike not gone out off business? You only need one loaf to feed you for the rest of your life :P

Comment: @TimCouwelier A single crust is the plane on one end. If you were thinking of cutting two crusts from a single end, that would be two pieces of a single crust totaling one crust in mass.

Comment: The real question here is how did you manage to stuff an infinitely long piece of bread into an infinite bag in a *finite amount of time*?

Comment: @Anon234_4521 You can't. Who knows what trade secret passed down the generations of the *Infinitely's Baking Shop* Mike possesses? ;)

Comment: Is the loaf  Aleph-null long or Aleph-one long?  :-)

Comment: BTW, if an infinite loaf has a finite cost -- as you implied in the statement that you would pay more for two loaves -- then any finite portion of the loaf has vanishlingly small value.

Comment: @Carl Witthoft Everyone knows the true value of the bread is all in the crust at the ends. The rest is just filler. Any finite portion has no value, unless it is the end crust, in which case it contains half the value (with the other half in the other end crust).

Comment: @Vepir I was thinking about cutting crust pieces from the sides, not the end. It's crust either way.

Comment: @TimCouwelier That would be too easy, but I guess the "crust" here is not precisely defined either, as the bottom is usually also crusty. (Can you measure the degree of crustiness?) As of now, Laurel seems to have posted this  idea as an answer.

Comment: Can you grab it from one side, slice off the end, put it back in the display and then grab it from the other side, slicing of the second end?

Comment: Am I right in saying the bread is [closed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closed_set)? Question and picture does not makes sense if it isn't I guess.

Comment: Anyway, there can only be one loaf. In fact the one loaf is the only thing that there can be.

Comment: There may be some merit in creating a charity for Jesse to collect "cut off bread crusts" for people who are crust-averse.   Also, the infinite loaf could also spawn a new field of study into the migratory patterns of yeast..

Comment: The baker couldn't pull bread from oven because he'd be pulling forever which means you'd only be ever able to get a short loaf with a crust at one end.  This riddle makes no sense.

Comment: I've closed this question because it's insufficiently defined. Mathematically, infinity *does not work that way*, and you need to define precisely what you mean - and you contradict yourself here.

Comment: Perhaps it should have been closed as too bread.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can ask for the freshly-baked bread, grabbing it by its center and

> asking that it be packed into the bag with the bread folded at the point you grabbed it, and with that point going into the bag first. The two ends would be within easy reach of the bag's opening, so you just cut them off, hold the bag in one hand and the crusts in the other.

Comment: TBH, this is simpler and better (in my opinion) than my initial solution, and also, my initial solution can lead to a "problem" regarding infinities as I've just realized, so I've decided to accept this instead.

Comment: I'm curious to know what the intended solution is.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 I've added a small hint for now.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60960/discussion-on-answer-by-lawrence-infinitely-long-loaf-of-bread).

Comment: Would the two ends really be in easy reach of the opening? I can't post an answer myself, but why fold the bread at all? Just grab by one end, cut crust, have it packed, cut-side in, cut other end which is definitely in easy reach of the opening for the infinitely long bag.

Comment: @RIanGillis That's certainly a valid solution; I like it. Welcome to Puzzing, by the way! You should be able to post answers regardless of your rep. Yours would be a good answer, and a valid variant of mine. It might even get around some of the objections others have made about this answer.

Comment: @RIanGillis As for whether the ends would be in easy reach - well, *some* part of the bread would be closest to the opening; might as well be the ends :) .

Comment: @Lawrence You could run into  a problem with a 'middle' of infinities. One of the ends may be quite far away indeed!

Comment: @WeckarE. Normally, I'd agree :) . In this puzzle, the 'middle' is explicitly stated as accessible, and the answer relies on Mike to do the heavy lifting.

Comment: @Lawrence I actually seemed to have read over the part where it is actually referred to as the center. My that's a lot of bread. Wonder if it has its own gravitational field?

Answer (score 36):

You are a physicist (or at least, you have heard a few physicists chatting at the water cooler).

Mike, your friend, is very obliging. Not obliging enough to chop off both ends of a loaf for you, but at least obliging enough to provide you with a sliced loaf.

You greet Mike and grab one end of a loaf from his display, immediately slicing off a crust. Then you get Mike to slice the remainder evenly. Mike deals with infinite loaves every day, so this is easy for him, even if it is, to put it mildly, somewhat difficult for you to do.

You then get Mike to place the slices into the infinite bag in this order: 1 slice, then 2 slices, then 3 and so on, each time incrementing the number of slices thrown into the bag.

This takes almost the whole day (Mike is working at a furious pace towards the end), which is why you don't get out of the shop until the end of the day.

When Mike is done, you discover to your surprise that your bag [now contains -1/12](https://plus.maths.org/content/infinity-or-just-112) of a slice of bread! You point this out to Mike, and ask for a proper loaf in exchange for the bag and its contents. Mike objects, saying that you still have a piece in your hand. You counter by saying that it would be unhygenic to return that piece, but he can keep one crust from the new loaf.

Mike mutters something under his breath while you grab a new loaf, surreptitiously slicing off the crust as you do so. Mike is already at the other end, slicing off the far crust as agreed. He wonders what he'll do with a finite piece of bread in his shop. He isn't as helpful now, unceremoniously dumping the rest of the loaf into a new bag and bidding you good day. You walk out with the bag in one hand and Jesse's two crusts in the other, determined to make it up to Mike by buying him a bottomless mug of coffee from the cafe next door once you've saved up enough.

Comment: Utilizing lateral-thinking tag, one can interpret the sum of integers as $-1/12$ indeed. I also like the story element in this one.

Comment: @Vepir I hope you enjoyed reading this answer as much as I did writing it. :)

Comment: That infinite sum doesn't actually work. You can't rearrange the elements of a divergent series. There might be some kind of function or special number or mapping that you can apply to the infinite sum that gives back -1/12, but it doesn't converge to -1/12 that way.

Comment: If you can surreptitiously slice one crust off while Mike slices the other off, you could have just done this with the initial loaf. This contradicts the third paragraph of the puzzle.

Comment: @Rawling You can't reach the other end. What you have is one crust from the first loaf, and one from the second. Mike doesn't ever give to your hand the crust from the far end on its own - either it goes into the bag with the rest of the slices, or Mike keeps it for himself.

Comment: @jpmc26 Ah, but it makes for a nice story :) . Besides, when those slices get thrown into the bag, they tend to get jostled about. If they get jostled in *just* the right way at just the right time ... instant -1/12 slice. :P

Comment: If you assume Mike can get to the far end in order to take the crust off or slice and bag the whole loaf, then he can get the far-end crust back to you. Given that, everything else seems a bit pointless.

Comment: @Rawling It's a *puzzle*. The constraints help avoid trivial solutions.

Comment: Yes, but coming up with a complicated solution doesn't mean you haven't bypassed the constraints.

Comment: We'd better move this to *chat* since a moderator has already objected to the discussion in comments. I'll click the "automatically move this discussion to chat" link - just a note that it will probably bring up an invitation that looks as if it was typed by me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60976/discussion-between-lawrence-and-rawling).

Comment: "The two ends would be within easy reach of the bag's opening" . I don't understand why this would be the case. It is an infinitely long bread and if you are folding it in the middle and putting the middle first into the bag, then the ends of the bread would still be infinitely far from the bag.

Comment: @HemantAgarwal If you’re asking about the other answer - the puzzle explicitly states that you can’t reach the end of the bread in finite time. This implies that Mike is the one who packed the infinite bread in the infinite bag. Since it is _in_ the bag, nothing sticks out.

Answer (score 14):

> I ask Mike to bake a loaf specially for me which is cut in half at the centre before going into the oven. When it is removed from the oven, I cut off the crusts in the middle for Jesse.

Comment: That was the *intended solution*! **Spoiler ahead** even if he does not bake on specific orders, simply wait until he starts baking a new one and ask for the same favor since you'll be buying it. And note the argument comes that at the point when it is baked, it seems you now have two breads for a price of one (since both parts have ends and are infinite)! But as soon as you cut the crusts and hide them away, then the two parts make a single cut loaf again, fixing the things, as Justin Ohms used this analogy in his answer.(Unless the crust is worth more than the rest of infinitely long bread?)

Comment: @Vepir; Re, "you now have two breads for a price of one."  Really?  But in your presentation of the puzzle you said, "you can afford only one loaf, and can't obtain ... any more loafs by any other ways."  You also implied that Mike does not negotiate; "Mike is also not very giving..."  So if the indended solution requires Mike to graciously bake you a special order---two loaves for the price of one---then the whole puzzle seems rather shabby.

Answer (score 13):

Trick question!

> An infinitely long loaf of bread would, by definition, not have more than one end because it keeps going forever.  As soon as you put two ends on a line it becomes a segment and is no longer infinite.  Therefore, the only option is to take the ends from two loaves.

Comment: That doesn't need to be the case. If something is infinite it still can have endpoints. Imagine a sentence starting with "This is a..." then infinitely many "...very very very..." followed by "...long sentence." But the definition of infinity is often used as "something that does not end" so this works under that interpretation! Mike was a fraud after all? :O

Comment: @Vepir, Sorry, but a sequence of infinitely many of something can not be "followed by" something else. that's not what "infinitely many" means.  You seem to be thinking of "infinity" as a number that happens to be bigger than any other number.  But, there is no such number.  Infinity is _not_ a number.  "Infinity" means "goes on forever."  It means "without end"

Comment: That depends on if Mike offers fractal bread or not.

Comment: @jameslarge It surely can, it simply depends how you define it. You are mistaking the *infinity here* with a *concept behind diverging set of elements*. The most common definition of infinity is something that does not end, however if you construct a sentence like the one I just did, or define breads like that, one can have an infinite object with *ends*. Define the bread: Take a normal bread with ends and cut it in half. Separate the ends a bit and fill the gap with more bread. Repeat infinitely many times. You now have two ends of bread separated with infinitely many bread. :)

Comment: @Vepir, Your question was not about a fractal loaf, your question was about an infinitely long loaf.  You even illustrated it by showing a picture of a bread loaf that was stretched in _one dimension_.  Any definition of "infinitely long" that stands up to scrutiny in that context is not going to permit the loaf to have more than one end.

Comment: @james large You're wrong. There is an infinite amount of numbers between 0 and 1. That's an infinite sequence despite having a defined start and end. Just consider that 0 and 1 are both ends of the loaf of bread. It's the same concept as an infinitely long piece of string.

Comment: @JoshuaBrodie There may be an infinite number of numbers between 0 and 1, but the interval from 0 to 1 is still 1 unit long, not of infinite length.

Comment: @JoshuaBrodie, The real numbers between zero and one comprise a _[continuum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_continuum)_, which is different from a [sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequence).

Comment: in·fin·i·ty
[inˈfinədē]
NOUN
mathematics
a number greater than any assignable quantity or countable number (symbol ∞).  Since we are talking length, you cannot have two ends, because at that point you would have an assignable length to the bread... it doesn't matter how many slices you can cut out of it.

Comment: @jameslarge While there are still good points to be made about how the infinite bread should be interpreted, you absolutely *can* discuss the idea of "a sequence of infinitely many things" followed by another. For example, if we give a new order the whole numbers by saying "0 is the biggest, and the positive numbers are ordered normally below that", then we do have the infinitely many positive numbers followed by 0: 1<2<3<...<0. This is not nonsense, but exactly what the ordinal called ω+1 represents.

Comment: @Mark S. you're still conflating infinite range vs infinite units.

You can have an infinite number of divisions within a finite range by changing the unit size to approach 0, but that doesn't have any effect on the finite property of the range being divided.

Since the question clearly states "infinitely long loaf of bread", indicating the length of the bread, we are talking about an infinite range, not just an infinitely small unit size.

Comment: @cyberconte, I agree with what you're saying about the bread; that's what I meant by "there are still good points to be made about how the infinite bread should be interpreted". I just wanted to say (off-topic) in my previous comment that the high-voted comment conflicted with modern mathematical understanding of infinity.

Answer (score 6):

This is [lateral-thinking](/questions/tagged/lateral-thinking), so I would:

> - Cut off a crust from the end I can reach.
> - Slice *laterally* and get some crust from the "top end" of the bread. You only need a slice the same size as the other piece of crust.

I tried to only buy these two pieces, and Mike told me I had to buy the entire infinite loaf. Joke's on him, never going to need to buy bread again!

Comment: what are you going to do in a month when you have infinite stale moldy bread?

Comment: Tim Couwelier actually mentions this idea in the comments of the post. I guess the crust isn't precisely defined in the story either.

Comment: My question (trying to figure out if this would be an accepted answer) predates this answer, my detailing the reasoning behind the question however only came after this answer.  I suggest this answer be judged as such: as Laurel's answer and not just piggybacking on my comment.

Comment: @ Sconibulus, mold spreads at a finite rate, just cut off the moldy part and make crutons from the stale part.

Comment: @mr23ceec water spreads at a finite rate too.

Comment: Water- yes. Dryness- no. It's the old "speed of dark" trick.

Answer (score 6):

This is actually a very easy problem, once you take into account the rules of the question.

1. Take an infinitely long loaf of bread from the shelf and cut off the crust on the end closest to you.  (1/2)
2. Put the infinitely long loaf of bread into your infinitely long shopping bag (which the puzzle states we have and are capable of putting an infinitely long loaf of bread into), placing it with the cut crust *down*.
3. The other end of the infinitely long loaf of bread is now sitting flush with the top of your infinitely long shopping bag, and you can easily cut it off. (2/2)

Voila.  One purchased loaf of bread, with two finite slices with crust.

Answer (score 4):

I tell Mike that

> I'll buy these two loaves of bread but first I want him to cut off the two ends that I can reach.  Once he hands me the two ends I tuck them away and tell him that I changed my mind and I'll just take the one infinitely long loaf that he has sitting there, the one that he has sitting there cut in half.  I'll grab the two ends that have no crust put them together and now I'm holding the middle of one infinitely long loaf.
>
>  Mike might get upset but it is only one infinitely long loaf that happens to be cut in half.

Comment: Playing with infinities :) Spoiler ahead: this can be used to resolve the problem occuring in the intended solution, in your favor. (But if one assumes the crust has all the value, and the infinite bread part is just a filler, to make sense of finite prices, then you just stole from Mike!)

Answer (score 3):

As any good bakery, Mike should offer to slice any bread for his customers. So I will ask him to cut the bread into infinite slices, handing me the first and the last slice in an extra bag. But I don't have infinite time to wait until he is finished. So how is he supposed to do infinite cuts in finite time?

> I ask him to take one minute to cut off the first slice (and put it in the extra bag), 1/2 minute to cut off the second, 1/4 minute to cut off the third, 1/8 minute to cut off the fourth and so on. After two minutes, he will have a pile of infinite slices with the last slice on top, which he can then take off and also put in the extra bag.

If you insist that the "can only handle the bread from the center" rule also applies to Mike, he can:

> start by cutting it in half, and then perform above algorithm on both halves one after another, handing me the last slice of each.

This method has the nice side-effect that I now have *two* bags of infinite slices of bread, so I can serve the second for breakfast in my Hilbert hotel.

Answer (score 1):

My answer involves a bit of back-and-forth: first, purchase a freshly baked loaf and

> Cut it in to two pieces, each of which are infinitely long.

Then you just have to trade

> the two loaves for two from the shelf.

This is a fair trade since

> Each of the two "half" loaves is infinite in extent, and therefore equal in value to a "whole" loaf.

Comment: These two loaves are missing a crust each, at the cutting point. Wouldn't that make them tiny bit less, a cut of infinity? They are distinguishable from the loaves on the shelves.

Comment: @Vepir That's not the problem. Infinity minus 1 is still infinity. But the true reason that the two halves are not equivalent is because they each have only one end-crust, which makes them half as valuable for anyone else who only likes the ends.

Answer (score 1):

> There is little practical difference between the crust on the end of the bread and the crust on the side. Therefore you can cut a six inch chunk of loaf off and then slice down the sides to take two "crusts" off the side. This has the wonderful advantage that Jesse can have more than two pieces of bread!

Answer (score 0):

I would have posted the same answer as @PeterTaylor (+1) but as he beat me too it...

> Cut off one end, take a single almost infinite Scooby-Doo-like bite out of the middle, then Cut off the other end.  Although eating an almost infinite loaf of bread like that would test even the largest cartoon bellies...